# Continue to get "Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed" when using fetch()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fetch data from a text file in my project and print it out as a test, but I continue to get the same error.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Stylesheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { beginQuiz } from './helperfunctions';
import myText from './sampleFile.js';

export const QuestionScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    fetch(myText)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log('There has been an error');
                  throw error;
                })
                console.log('done');
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is the question screen</Text>
            <Button title='Sample Button'/>
        </View>
    )
  };
```

Here is the sampleFile.js:

```
var myText = 'This is a sample text file.'
```

Comment: is your text file actually `.js` file? just import it -- no need to `fetch`

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to practice the fetch command. Is it possible to fetch a variable in a file like this?